# Android app that installs thro' Android studio doesn't install independently

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I created an app using android studio and I could install and run it from android studio on two devices (mobile phones) in developer mode.
But when I picked up the same `apk` file from the project folder and transferred it to the devices and attempted to install them, I simply get error messages to the effect 'App not Installed' (on one device), or 'App file seems to be corrupt'(on first attempt to install) or 'There was an error while parsing' (on later attempts). How to rectify this?

I attempted transfer it vis pen drive or shared drives like one drive. The result is the same.
And none of the existing solutions here in Stack overflow or other sites seemed to help.

Comment: Open logcat, present at the bottom, and then try installing the files. Post log where it crashes. It is nearly impossible to state the reason behind it without seeing the code or the log cat file.

Comment: Logcat is in Android Studio. I have no issues installing from Android Studio onto the mobile device. Also Logcat doesn't have any message when I do so (I just checked).  I have issue only when I attempt to install the .apk file on mobile from, say, download folder, whatsapp, or a shared drive etc. 
I am attempting this because I want to ask my friends to check the app on their mobile by just sending them the .apk that is an unsigned development version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the context of the question, three cases arise:-

1. **Android Studio creates Unsigned APK.**
2. **Incompatible SDK version.**
3. **Phone doesn't allow installation from unknown sources.**

## Android Studio creates Unsigned APK

Unsigned APKs will not run either on the emulator or on the actual device. Generally, applications are exported as **Signed** Package applications. But if in case, it is not, then it can be changed.

1. Go to `Project`
2. Click `Android Tools`
3. Export `Signed Application`

Again, by default, the applications are `signed`, but just in case if it is not, then you know how to change it.

## Incompatible SDK version

Another situation that may arise is with the in variation between `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

The problem is, that the `.apk` file is created with a higher SDK version, while the phone is running on a lower SDK version

To change it, consider doing this:

1. Go to `Gradle Scripts`
2. Open `build.gradle` (Module)

There, make the necessary changes, for example:

```
 defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

It might be informal, but I always keep `minSdkVersion` smaller than `targetSdkVersion` with a minimum difference of 10.

## Phone doesn't allow installation from unknown sources

This is one of the most common reasons, why the `.apk` file won't get install on your standalone device.

So consider changing the settings:

1. Open `Settings`
2. Open `Security and Privacy`
3. Under the `App Installation` select on `Unknown source installations`.
4. If you were to download the `.apk` file from another app, like `WhatsApp` , then select that particular app.

**Note:** This may vary from device to device. But on most of the devices, it will work.

## Alternative

If none of the above works, then do the following:-

1. Go to `File` -> `Invalidate cache and restart`
2. Go to `Build`
3. Then `Build APK(s)`
4. After the building is done, then click locate and proceed to install it.

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Regarding the 3 cases you mentioned,   
- 2 is not the reason, since it runs when I run on the mobile device from Android studio.
- 3 is also not the reason, since I have taken the step you have mentioned.
- 1, I presumed a debug version will not be a signed version  But the key thing is when I attempt installation, it says 'App file may be corrupt' or 'error while parsing' , though I use the same .apk file that runs from Android Studio.  
Is the debug version not runnable outside Android Studio? 
In any case I couldn't find the menu items you have mentioned for signing.

Comment: @HariMannarsamy added a 4th solution, see if it works.

Comment: Hey ILoveLogCat,
It worked like magic, at last!!! 
Thank you very much. 
Hope I don't have to keep doing it for every build, but then that's fine, if I have to share.
Thanks again!

Comment: Thats great. You may accept it as an answer,  so that it will help others in future.